# Are mixtures of finely ground solid fertilizer compounds stable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, solutions, stability, ionic-compounds

If I had a combination of the following as finely ground powders, would it be relatively stable, or would they react to form other compounds?

Sodium Nitrate
Ammonium Nitrate
Calcium Nitrate
Potassium Nitrate
Magnesium Sulfate 
Potassium Chloride
Ammonia Sulfate
Copper Sulfate 
Zinc Sulfate 
Ferrous Sulfate 
Manganese Sulfate
Sodium Molybdate
Monoammonium Phosphate
Boric Acid
Sodium Hydroxide

(Some of course being hydrates)

Comment: General rule: Do not mix things, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I mix these compounds all the time in the presence of water.

Comment: I found with sad experience ,some release ammonia gas ( I do not remember which. I do not mix such materials now.)

Comment: Please read up on ammonium nitrate.

Comment: Quite a lot of those are dangerous just by themselves, never mind when finely ground of mixed. If you want to see why ammonium nitrate is problematic, go visit Beirut which was largely destroyed when a mishandled large store of it exploded.

Answer (score 3):

All depends on amounts, concentrations and ratios. It is a big difference between:

- being solid/just being dissolved  together
- being together in diluted solution

Even in cooking recipes, conditions of mixing ingredients do matter.

Reactions and precipitations often have concentration thresholds. Higher concentrations lead to more intense reactions or  precipitations, undergoing in higher degree, or even to qualitatively new reactions.

---

Aside of chemical stability, there is danger it would absorb air humidity and all the fine powder could form a single big block.

---

Sodium hydroxide releases ammonia gas from all ammonium salts when they are all solid or being dissolved.

When being dissolved:

- Sodium hydroxide precipitates hydroxides of transition metals like copper, iron, zinc, manganese.
- Sulfates precipitate calcium as calcium sulfate.
- Phosphate can precipitate calcium and will precipitate copper, zinc, iron, manganese.
- Molybdate may precipitate calcium, copper, zinc, iron, manganese.
- Boric acid may precipitate calcium, copper, zinc, iron, manganese.

Generally, it is not good to mix together

- alkaline compounds (or ones preferring alkaline    conditions)

  - sodium hydroxide, sodium molybdate
- acidic compounds (or ones preferring acidic conditions)

  - copper sulfate, zinc sulfate, ferrous sulfate, manganese sulfate, monoammonium phosphate, ammonia sulfate, ammonium nitrate

It may be advantageous to have

- major nutritients ($\ce{Ca}$,$\ce{N}$, $\ce{P}$, $\ce{K}$) in solid state, and rather course than fine.
- minor ones in a stock solution(s)

---

If you insist on mixing them, then I would suggest to keep sodium hydroxide alone in its original state and keep the rest in separate compatible mixtures, in the sense of above.

Comment: @BuckThorn I do not handle them. :-) // Well, the powder mixture is not supposed to stay in that state forever, but is intended to be dissolved // Mix powdered ammonia salts with alkaline compounds and sniff that. // If the OP insists on mixing them, then I would suggest at least to separate them into several compatible mixtures.

Comment: P.S.: I got it now about sodium hydroxide. :-) Sure, aside, and not as powder.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Galveston explosion or the Halifax explosion on the web. The city of Texas City or Halifax was destroyed, and I am not sure if the chemical was "finely ground". There are oxidizing and reducing agents in the mix, release of ammonia gas or precipitation of metal ions are your least concerns. Knowing the names of chemicals is not sufficient. You must know the properties and you have quite a list.

If you must mix these do so as a dilute solution paying particular attention to the order of mixing to prevent unwanted intermediate reactions and avoid cross contamination. Again learn the properties.